# Adding back codes to hyperlink in asp

Tags: asp.net

I have first this

```
<li><asp:HyperLink id="logoutBtn" NavigateUrl="login.aspx" Text="Logout" runat="server"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout </asp:HyperLink></li>
```

But I think it goes first to the page before he runs the back code which is this.

```
public void logoutBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session.Clear();
    Response.Redirect("../login.aspx");
}
```

So basically I can still access any site because the `Session` is not cleared.

How can I achieve that whenever I click the `HyperLink` the code is fired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of a hyperlink is to navigate the user to another destination. (Plus, you don't have a click eventhandler attached to you hyper link, that will run your code behind.)

If you want to run server-side code use a good old `button`:

```
<asp:Button ID="logoutBtn" runat="server" onclick="logoutBtn_Click" Text="Logout" />  

public void logoutBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session.Clear();
    Response.Redirect("../login.aspx");
}
```

If you want to use an `asp:Hyperlink` control to logout the user, navigate him to a specific logout page:

```
<li><asp:HyperLink id="logoutBtn" NavigateUrl="logout.aspx" Text="Logout" runat="server"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout </asp:HyperLink></li>
```

Create the logout.aspx page and in the Page_Load event, log the user out:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session.Clear();
    Response.Redirect("../login.aspx");
}
```

Comment: I can't do the `<asp:Button>` because it will mess up the template. And in my 2 cents I'm trying to not have your second option as much as possible. But if there is no other way. Well I'll accept it. Thank you for the explanation

Comment: Then style the button until it fits in your template. That's what css is for, right?